# PowerShell Adding a pair to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm having a `System.Array` that defines the permissions of a specific security group on a folder, which looks like this:

```
$Permissions
C\Department                     : FINANCE
BEL ROL-STAFF-FIN Accountants    : L
BEL ROL-STAFF-SA Sales Employees : F

C\Department                     : SALES
BEL ROL-STAFF-FIN Accountants    : C
BEL ROL-STAFF-SA Sales Employees : F

$Permissions.Count # Returns 2
```

What I would like to know is how can I add another security group?

If I would like to add the security group `BEL ROL-STAFF-IT Service Desk` with the value `F` to the example above, the result would be:

```
$Permissions
C\Department                     : FINANCE
BEL ROL-STAFF-FIN Accountants    : L
BEL ROL-STAFF-SA Sales Employees : F
BEL ROL-STAFF-IT Service Desk    : F

C\Department                     : SALES
BEL ROL-STAFF-FIN Accountants    : C
BEL ROL-STAFF-SA Sales Employees : F
BEL ROL-STAFF-IT Service Desk    : F

$Permissions.Count # Returns 2
```

It seems easy to just add a `row` to an array, but how does one add a key/value pair to an existing `row` in the array so the count stays the same?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I had to add a `NoteProperty` to a single `row`or `$Item` as I named it below:

```
[int]$i = '0'
foreach ($Item in $Permissions) {

    Write-Host "Item $([int]$i++)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $Item

    foreach ($d in $DefaultPermissions) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $Item -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $d.GroupName -Value $d.Permissions
    }

    $Item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add an hashtable to your array

```
$i=0
$permissions|%{
    $permissions[$i]+=@{'BEL ROL-STAFF'='F'}
    $i++
}
```